# Codable Struct for Firebase Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore document which contains an array of 'map' objects of Type String:Any

So like his

```
myArray.                                       <-- Firestore (array)
  0                                            <-- Array item which is a Firestore (map)
    timestamp: May 30, 2023 12:00:00 PM        <-- Firestore (timestamp)
    text: "ABCD"                               <-- Firestore (string)
```

I want to write a corresponding Codable Struct and tried it this way but it doesn't conform to Decodable protocol

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var myArray: Array<[String:Any]>
}
```

I want to be able to update myArray with:

```
db.collection("myDocuments").document(document.documentID).updateData(["myArray": FieldValue.arrayUnion([myStruct])]
```

How can I rewrite the Struct to make it Codable?

*** EDIT ***

I changed to this

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var myArray: Array<MyData>?
}

struct MyData: Codable {
    var name: String
    var timestamp: Date
}
```

Instance of myStruct

```
let myData = MyData(name: "name", timestamp: Date())

let myStruct = MyStruct (
    myArray: [MyData]
)
```

Writing to Firestore is OK

```
db.collection("data").addDocument(from: myStruct)
```

Fails here

```
db.collection("data").document(document.documentID).updateData(["myArray": FieldValue.arrayUnion([myData])])
```

With a cryptic error..

Comment: Make Any Codable, you can use an enum to create different cases for different types. Or create a model with time stamp and text variables

Comment: @loremipsum I edited the post with what appears to partially work...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry for not responding until now.  I don't have the error anymore.  I found a solution that works for me and have moved on to something else.  I'll have to go back to what I did to post my answer.